# Scrolling image overlay on fixed image container

Tags: html, css

I have a case where I want to make an image overlay for sold items. I made that with a php-generated div with transparent png background, which is positioned absolutely in the anchored container, above the product image, this is the HTML code:

```
<div class="termekkep-holder eladva ">
<a href="http://tango-antik.hu/herendi-porcelan-szololevel-alaku-asztali-kinalo-talka-a-kozkedvelt-viktoria-mintaval/" title="Herendi porcelán “szőlőlevél” alakú">
<div class="eladott"></div> 
<img src="http://tango-antik.hu/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/Tango-fotok-_02241-250x250.jpg" class="attachment-termekkep wp-post-image" alt="Tango-fotok-_0224">          
</a>    
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.eladott {
background: url(img/eladva.png) no-repeat top center transparent;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background-size: 100%;
}

.termekkep-holder .eladott {
background-position: center center;
    width: 230px;
    height: 230px;
}
```

It works great, all until the time when the parent div gets bigger, with the need to scroll, then the overlay div stays at the screen space, and not above the image.

Any idea how it can be solved?

This is the link:
http://tango-antik.hu/porcelanok/
(try scrolling the inside part with the products)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `position: relative;` to `.termekkep-holder`:

```
.termekkep-holder {
    position: relative;
}
```

The idea is that when you set `position: absolute;` to an element and you want it to stick to its parent, then you need to explicitly set your parent's `position: relative;`, even though it is the default value. Here is a demo, but I added an outer `<div>` just to mimic the scrolling:

```css
.eladott {
background: url("http://tango-antik.hu/wp-content/themes/Tangobolt-template/img/eladva.png") no-repeat top center transparent;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background-size: 100%;
}

.termekkep-holder .eladott {
background-position: center center;
    width: 230px;
    height: 230px;
}

.termekkep-holder {
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 300px; overflow-y: scroll;">
<div class="termekkep-holder eladva ">
<a href="http://tango-antik.hu/herendi-porcelan-szololevel-alaku-asztali-kinalo-talka-a-kozkedvelt-viktoria-mintaval/" title="Herendi porcelán “szőlőlevél” alakú">
<div class="eladott"></div> 
<img src="http://tango-antik.hu/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/Tango-fotok-_02241-250x250.jpg" class="attachment-termekkep wp-post-image" alt="Tango-fotok-_0224">          
</a>    
</div>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
</div>
```